# How to pause Media Player in a different activity?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have been searching around for info on this subject and have not found a lot. Maybe I'm not looking hard enough but whatever. In my main activity I establish "private MediaPlayer mainSound;" I set looping to true and then start the media player. That all works fine but I want to pause this sound in a different activity. In my other activity if I type in  "mainSound.pause();" or something like that it says to make a local variable caled mainSound.

How do I make it so I can pause the mediaplayer that was declared in the main activity in my other activity? Do I set it to public? Thanks, and also I am quite new to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media Player and If Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873411/media-player-and-if-statements)

Comment: Please see the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875094/how-to-change-the-media-player-from-a-different-activity