# How to change the media player from a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I was wondering if I can declare a media player variable in one activity and then pause or stop it in a separate activity. How would I go about this or is there another way? Thanks

Comment: I don't think controlling variables in one activity via another one is a good idea. May I ask you your use case?

Comment: Well I wanted to have a media player loop in the background that can be changed in any other activity. Like when a button is clicked in another activity the media player would pause or resume. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a fan of static vars. I'd prefer doing something like this

Android Manifest

```
<activity name="Player" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

This former ensures that you have only one instance of the activity running, and that all intents leading to starting that activity are delivered via its `onNewIntent()`

```
class Player extends Activity{
  public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com....PLAY";
  public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com...PAUSE";

  public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PLAY)){
      //Play
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_PAUSE){
      //Pause
    }
  }
}
```

And from the calling activity, you could invoke

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
playIntent.setAction(Player.ACTION_PLAY);
```

and

```
Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(this, Player.class);
pauseIntent.setAction(Player.ACTION_PAUSE);
```

Comment: Ok, and in the public static final strings what would I put in place of "com....PLAY" and "com....PAUSE"?

Comment: Use com.your.package.name.PLAY. This is the convention. And please accept the answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Either you can use static variable of `MediaPlayer` in your activity, so that you can access your media player  by using `YourActivityName.mediaplayer.stop()`

or

use a `service` class

 I prefer `service` class

Comment: Well I tried the static variable and that seems to work fine. Is there a problem with it if I'm only using it for like one button in one activity?